# Bind resource to a PDO LOB param on SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm facing an issue about LOB binding with PHP PDO & SQLite. According to the documentation, in order to bind a LOB value on a placeholder, we should use something like:

```
$lob = fopen($path, 'rb');

$conn = new PDO('sqlite:/my/db/path.sqlite');
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT field FROM table WHERE lob_column = ?');
$stmt->bindValue(1, $lob, \PDO:PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

If I put a LOB value in a WHERE clause, it always ends up with a false result which means an error occured. Anyway, this piece of wode works well with PDO Mysql or PDO PgSql but seems not working with PDO SQLite. Am I facing a PHP bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. you'll also find the same bug for PDO:PARAM_FLOAT